# Oracle SQL Developer : Insert into values as select from another sql file

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

Is it possible to insert the values into Oracle SQL Table from SQL Developer as a result of external script

```
INSERT
INTO TABLE_A
  (
    ID,
    VERSION
  ) VALUES (@select.sql)
```

Statement in the file select.sql looks like

```
SELECT ID, VERSION from TABLE_X;
```

Comment: Why you can not write insert query inside sql file "select.sql"?

Comment: Well of cource I can but that was not a question :)

Comment: It will be just a simple solution)

Comment: This will work in SQL*Plus and SQLcl if you place `@select.sql` in a line on its own and fix the INSERT syntax (either `insert...select` or `insert...values`, not both). Is that sufficient? It doesn't work in SQL Developer using F5 ('Run as script').

Answer (score 2):

This will not work in SQL Developer 20 using 'Run as script' (F5) (or in a PL/SQL Developer Command window, for that matter). If it has to work from SQL Developer, you are out of luck.

It will work in SQL*Plus and SQLcl if you clean up the syntax and place the call on its own line.

**test_insert.sql**

```
insert into table_a
( id
, version )
@@select.sql
/
```

**select.sql**

```
select rownum, 1
from   xmltable('1 to 10')
```

(note that you have to decide which script contains the terminating `;` or `/`.)

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 9 11:27:40 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed Sep 09 2020 11:26:30 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0


SQL> @test_insert

10 rows created.

SQL>

SQL> l
  1  insert into table_a
  2  ( id
  3  , version )
  4  select rownum, 1
  5* from   xmltable('1 to 10')
```

Comment: Ha! Thank you for showing me that *impossible* actually *is* possible.

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, I don't think that it is possible.

Here's what might work, if you put some effort in it:

- if `select.sql` file is located on a database server, in a directory which is a *source* for an Oracle directory object, and
- if user - which is supposed to run this code - has `read` privilege on that directory, then
- write a PL/SQL script which would

  - use `UTL_FILE` to read `select.sql`, *compose* a statement (your example shows only one line; I guess there might be complex statements in there) and put it into a local variable
  - alternatively, you could even use `select.sql` file as an external table with just one column
  - compose another - `insert` - statement (note that yours is *wrong*; there shouldn't be the `values` keyword there)
  - execute it using `execute immediate` (so yes, this is dynamic SQL)

Would I want to do that? I don't think so, but - you might, now that you know *how*.